# Linked list in C, no member error

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to write a database for class in which I read all the key values in from a file (formatted keyNULL BYTEvalueNULL BYTE etc). I amt rying to use a linked list for this, but I get the error that the struct has no next value. Please help me!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "sdbm.h"

static FILE *db;
static bool opened = false;
static int err = 0, keyLen = 8;

typedef struct {
  char *name;
  Key *next;
} Key;

static Key *head = NULL,*tail = NULL; 
/**
 * Create new database with given name. You still have
 * to sdbm_open() the database to access it. Return true
 * on success, false on failure.
 */
bool sdbm_create( const char *name ) { //Errors: 1) fopen failed 2) fclose failed on new db
  db = fopen(name, "w");
  if (db == NULL) {
    printf("Couldn't create file %s\n",name);
    err = 1;
    return false;
  }
  if (fclose(db) == EOF) {
    printf("Couldn't close created file %s\n",name);
    err = 2;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
/**
 * Open existing database with given name. Return true on
 * success, false on failure.
 */
bool sdbm_open( const char *name ) { //Errors: 3) couldn't open database
  db = fopen(name,"r+");
  if (db == NULL) {
    err = 3;
    printf("Couldn't open database file %s\n",name);
    return false;
  }
  opened = true;
  int c;
  bool inKey = true;
  int currKey[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
  while ((c = getc(db)) != EOF)  {
    if (!inKey && c == '\0') {
      inKey = true;
    }
    else if (inKey && c == '\0') {
      if (tail != NULL) {
        tail->next = malloc(sizeof(Key));
        tail = tail->next;
      }
      else {
        tail = malloc(sizeof(Key));
        head = tail;
      }
      tail->next = NULL;
      tail->name = currKey;

    }
    else if (inKey) { 
      currKey[keyLen] = c;
      keyLen++;
    }
  }
}
/**
 * Synchronize all changes in database (if any) to disk.
 * Useful if implementation caches intermediate results
 * in memory instead of writing them to disk directly.
 * Return true on success, false on failure.
 */
//bool sdbm_sync();

/**
 * Close database, synchronizing changes (if any). Return
 * true on success, false on failure.
 */
bool sdbm_close() { // Errors: 5) Couldn't close database
  if (fclose(db) == EOF) {
    err = 5;
    printf("Couldn't close database.\n");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
/**
 * Return error code for last failed database operation.
 */
int sdbm_error() {
  return err;
}

/**
 * Is given key in database?
 */
//bool sdbm_has( const char *key );

/**
 * Get value associated with given key in database.
 * Return true on success, false on failure.
 *
 * Precondition: sdbm_has(key)
 */
//bool sdbm_get( const char *key, char *value );

/**
 * Update value associated with given key in database
 * to given value. Return true on success, false on
 * failure.
 *
 * Precondition: sdbm_has(key)
 */
//bool sdbm_put( const char *key, const char *value );

/**
 * Insert given key and value into database as a new
 * association. Return true on success, false on
 * failure.
 *
 * Precondition: !sdbm_has(key)
 */
//bool sdbm_insert( const char *key, const char *value );

/**
 * Remove given key and associated value from database.
 * Return true on success, false on failure.
 *
 * Precondition: sdbm_has(key)
 */
//bool sdbm_remove( const char *key );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition should be like

```
typedef struct Key{
  char *name;
  struct Key *next; // <-- Note `struct` here
}Key;
```

You cannot use just `Key`[without explicitly writing struct before it] inside the definition of the structure because the structure is not yet defined [typedefed]

Comment: You're the best. It works now. Can't wait until I know C and don't make these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: One question, does this change the type of next? Is it now a struct Key * or is it still just a Key *?

Comment: @David Watson : It is a `struct Key*`. `typdef` is just used as a placeholder/synonym for another type.

Comment: @David: After the typedef, 'struct Key' and 'Key' mean the same thing.  If you missed the distinction, within the struct definition is *before* the typedef takes affect, so there you need 'struct Key'.

Comment: @Prasoon: I'm not sure leaving out the struct name (in the first line) is valid C; though as you have it, gcc accepts line 3 (actually, gcc accepts *any* name on line 3, but incorrect names produce invalid debug info).

Comment: This answer is *incorrect* unless you replace `typedef struct {` with `typedef struct Key {`. As it stands, you're declaring a pointer to an incomplete type `struct Key` which is never completed, not a pointer to type `Key` (which is `typedef`'d to an anonymous `struct`).

Answer (score 1):

While I'm digging my compiler out, can you try changing the declarations to:

```
typedef struct Key_ {
  char *name;
  struct Key_ *next;
} Key;
```

and let us know if that helps?  I think you may be using the typedef before it's declared.

Comment: My compiler didn't complain about that either way - with the struct tag name, or with the typedef, either way was fine.  It did complain about a couple of void* casts, and that currKey was an array of int and couldn't be assigned to a pointer to char.

Comment: You can use the same name, no need for an underscore suffix.

Comment: Fair enough.  It runs in my mind that there's some issue either with an old standard, or with cross-compatibility with C++, where having the struct tag name collide with the typedef was an issue, so when I'm writing C, I tend to use this style.  It may be out of date.

Comment: Possibly with *really* old compilers, but standard C++ lets you typedef a name to the same name.  (E.g. even `struct A {}; typedef A A;` is valid.)