# expected specifier-qualifier-list before

Tags: c

I have this struct type definition:

```
typedef struct {
    char *key;
    long canTag;
    long canSet;
    long allowMultiple;
    confType *next;
} confType;
```

When compiling, gcc throws this error:

```
conf.c:6: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘confType’
```

What does this mean? It doesn't seem related to other questions with this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linked list in C, no member error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869110/linked-list-in-c-no-member-error)

Comment: @Prasoon: Yes, but the accepted answer there is incomplete.

Comment: @schot : Sorry I didn't see the comments. Corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608175/what-does-this-error-mean-error-expected-specifier-qualifier-list-before-type

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You used confType before you declared it. (for next). Instead, try this:

```
typedef struct confType {
    char *key;
    long canTag;
    long canSet;
    long allowMultiple;
    struct confType *next;
} confType;
```

Comment: Thanks! It's obvious now that I've seen this.

Answer (score 22):

JoshD's answer now is correct, I usually go for an equivalent variant:

```
typedef struct confType confType;

struct confType {
    char *key;
    long canTag;
    long canSet;
    long allowMultiple;
    confType *next;
};
```

When you only want to expose opaque pointers, you put the `typedef` in your header file (interface) and the `struct` declaration in your source file (implementation).